# How to block outgoing traffic to ip in IP tables in K8S

Tags: docker, kubernetes, iptables, kubernetes-pod

I want block outgoing traffic to the ip (eg-DB) in IP tables in K8s.

I know that in K8s ip tables exist only at node level.

and I'm not sure in which file changes should be made and what is the command or changes required.

Please help me with this query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly run the IPtable command (ex. `iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT`) on top of a node if that's fine.

however file depends on the OS : `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` this is for **ipv4**

i would suggest checking out the **Network policy** in Kubernetes using that you can block the outgoing traffic.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

No extra setup is required like Istio or anything.

Cluster security you can handle using the network policy in the backend it uses IP tables only.

For example to block traffic on specific CIDR or IP by applying the YAML only

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 5978
```

Comment: haha, quick lazy solution, although istio is not bad unless person know how to handle it.

Comment: In addition to my question. Can I use this if my db is not in pod/node. DB IP is given in jdbc url?

Comment: So you mean there is pod running inside that app Config have one db ip and you want to restrict all outbound traffic request to tht ip ?

Comment: In background it uses ip table hand you can block external traffic, give it try once.

Comment: Actually I will be providing DB1 ip but I don't want it to go to DB2 IP. Basically it's like security layer for DB2 IP such that no calls go to that DB2 ip, if in case I messed up and gave DB2 IP address in spring url.

Comment: Does the NetworkPolicy log denied traffic anywhere?

Comment: probably i think will be at local node storage, `/var/log/network`

Answer (score 2):

You could deploy istio and specifically the istio egress gateway.

This way you will be able to manage outgoing traffic within the istio manifest